# Why did I receive a 1095-C from one employer and a 1095-B from another?

Tags: taxes, healthcare, documents, tax-forms

I changed jobs in May 2017. My former employer sent me a 1095-C tax form and my current, substantially larger employer sent me a 1095-B. Why might I not have received a 1095-C from my current employer?

Comment: How many employees does each have?